# Code runs fine on iPhone 5s+, not previous versions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I run this bit of code on an iPhone 5s or higher, it executes as expected. But when I run it on any version lower than a 5s (5, 4s, 4), it does not.

It is supposed to go into the first if statement, ignore the second if statement and execute the else. This works fine in any version over 5s in the simulator, but when I run it on a 5 or 4 it goes into the second if statement... instead of ignoring it and executing the else.

currentProduct.productID is an NSNumber

anything that could help me out would be very appreciated!

```
    NSNumber *currentProductID = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:4121];

if (productPurchased != YES) {
    if (currentProduct.productID != currentProductID) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"InAppPurchaseViewController" sender:nil];
    } else {
        [self showActivityView];
        [self performSelector:@selector(configureExam) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
```

Comment: Be careful with comparing directly to `YES`. That's not safe. `YES` is a specific value. It can lead to false positives. You should be doing the comparison as `if(!productPurchased)`. Not related to your question, but still something to watch out for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `!=` (or `==`) to compare two objects.

Change the `if` to:

```
if (![currentProduct.productId isEqual:currentProductID]) {
```

On a side note, use modern syntax to create the number:

```
NSNumber *currentProductID = @4121;
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare `NSNumber` you could use

1. `compare:` which returns `NSComparisonResult`

   ```
   NSNumber *currentProductID = @4121;
   if ([currentProduct.productId compare:currentProductID] != NSOrderedSame) {
   }
   ```
2. `isEqualToNumber:`

   ```
   NSNumber *currentProductID = @4121;
   if (![currentProduct.productId isEqualToNumber:currentProductID]) {
   }
   ```
3. `intValue` and compare it like what you did.

   ```
   NSNumber *currentProductID = @4121;
   if ([currentProduct.productId intValue] != [currentProductID intValue]) {
   }
   ```

Comment: This has nothing to do with 32 vs 64 bit. It's a simple matter is mistakenly using `!=` to compare two objects. BTW - In option #3, why bother making `currentProductID` an `NSNumber`? Just compare `[currentProduct.productId intValue]` directly to `4121`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification about 64bits. I'll take that bit of the answer out. And option#3. you are right. Could just use int.

Comment: 64 bit has something to do with the fact the code works on 5S, but it's an implementation detail that should not be relied on: Using the above answer is correct. Just for the record, in 64 bit, most integers NSNumbers are using uniquified tagged pointers, thus the program working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by extracting integer values from `NSNumbers` and then compare them. Like below

```
if ([currentProduct.productID integerValue] != [currentProductID integerValu]) {
```